# WordPress plugin for a contact form builder, which also allows to save entered form as a WordPress post

Tags: gratis, wordpress

I'm looking for a WordPress plugin which lets me build custom (contact) forms. I also need that form to create a post in WordPress upon submission.

Currently I'm using [TDO Mini Forms](http://thedeadone.net/download/tdo-mini-forms-wordpress-plugin/) plugin, but the plugin has a pretty severe security hole & has been abandoned by the author.

Plugin should:

- Allow me to build custom forms
- Inherit current WordPress theme
- Allow me to set certain fields as required, also allow for minimum, max character limits
- Allow me to save the entered form as a post with desired category, tags & support for custom fields
- Send emails of submissions to WordPress blog admins (preferably) or to a specific set of users
- Be free

I think Gravity Forms & Form Ninja allow me to do most of these, but are paid, and I'm looking at a free alternative. Also TDO Mini Forms, but for reasons mentioned about I can't use that.

Is there a free plugin which does what I want?

Comment: I only have experience with [Contact Form 7](http://contactform7.com/), which does not save as a post, but [this post](http://anthonymarchese.us/gravity-forms-alternatives/) does a good job of recommending some low or no-cost alternatives to Gravity Forms.

Comment: Have you looked at Jetpack? It includes a contact form function (which is arguably better than Contact Form 7). It doesn't save as a post, but does send you an email AND also saves it in the admin under a new section that it adds called "Feedback". Jetpack also comes with several features previously only available to Wordpress.com blogs.

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt you'll find a software with those characteristics. Any of the cited products, Gravity Forms, Form Ninja, Contact Form 7, Jetpack, should offer an entry point for you to add this piece of functionality:

> Allow me to save the entered form as a post with desired category, tags & support for custom fields

You will be looking for `do_action` calls inside the plugins' code. But normally this info is on the plugins' FAQ.

The first 3 requirements are pretty much default in all plugins. Sending emails too, but maybe needing settings adjustments or custom functionality.